# How to calculate the sum of rows with the maximum date country wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to calculate the sum of the rows with the maximum date per country and if the country has more than one province then it should add the confirmed cases with the maximum date . For ex [input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAqc6.jpg)
 This is the input that I have and the output should be 
[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1yab.jpg)

So the output for China is 90 which is the sum of Tianjin and Xinjiang for the maximum date which is 02-03-2020.
And since Argentina does not have any province it's output is 20 for the highest date which is again the same as above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you fill in your empty province values, you could use groupby to pull out the Date and then another groupby to get the sum of values.

```
input['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(input['Date'], format="%d-%m-%Y")
input = input.fillna("dummy")
input.loc[input.groupby(["Country/Region", "Province/State"]).Date.idxmax()].groupby(["Country/Region"])["Confirmed"].sum()
```

Comment: This does not work if we change the month of the date. for ex if we have two dates as '04-09-2020' and '12-08-2020' then it would take '12-08-2020' as the highest date because it is mismatching the month with day but instead it should take '04-09-2020' as the highest date

Comment: You can specify the format of your date using the to_datetime() argument with the format parameter. I think all the answers here are using month-day-year, but it's very simple to change that to day-month-year. I'll update my answer to reflect this.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Answer (score 1):

The strategy is to sort the values such that the last date is the first row of the Country/Region-Province/State pairs, then roll up the dataset twice, filtering the max date between roll ups.

First, sorting to put most recent dates at the top of each group:

```
(df
 .sort_values(['Country/Region', 'Province/State', 'Date'], ascending=False))

         Date Country/Region Province/State  Confirmed
3  02-03-2020          China       Xinjiang         70
2  01-03-2020          China       Xinjiang         30
1  02-03-2020          China        Tianjin         20
0  01-03-2020          China        Tianjin         10
```

Then rolling up to Country/Region-Province/State and taking the most recent date:

```
(df
 .sort_values(['Country/Region', 'Province/State', 'Date'], ascending=False)
 .groupby(['Country/Region', 'Province/State'])
 .first())

                                     Date  Confirmed
Country/Region Province/State                       
China          Tianjin         02-03-2020         20
               Xinjiang        02-03-2020         70
```

Finally, rolling up again to just Country/Region:

```
(df
 .sort_values(['Country/Region', 'Province/State', 'Date'], ascending=False)
 .groupby(['Country/Region', 'Province/State'])
 .first()
 .groupby('Country/Region').sum())

                Confirmed
Country/Region           
China                  90
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]

## Basic Solution is to use the power of pandas and multiple methods that can jointly solve your problem

#### So we first convert the Date Column to a Datetime Column

- Bascially , String to Datetime Type Conversion
- Then we sort by the 'Date' Column
- Then we .groupby() - Country and Date aggregating over 'Confirmed' Column (SUM) - Finally we drop_duplicates() keeping the last, which gives you the latest for any particular country

  `df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
  df.sort_values(by = 'Date' , inplace = True)`

`df.groupby(['Country','Date']).agg({'Confirmed':'sum'}).reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset = 'Country' , keep = 'last')`

Comment: This does not work if we change the month of the date. for ex if we have two dates as '04-09-2020' and '12-08-2020' then it would take '12-08-2020' as the highest date because it is mismatching the month with day but instead it should take '04-09-2020' as the highest date

Answer (score 0):

```
 df.groupby(['Date', 'Country/Region'],as_index = False).sum().groupby(['Country/Region']).agg('last').reset_index()


   Country/Region   Date    Confirmed
  0 Argentina      2020-03-02   20
  1 China          2020-03-02   90
  2 France         2020-03-02   70
```